# AngularJS validations popup on page load in firefox

Tags: angularjs, validation, firefox

I have used angularJS validations like `ng-required` and `ng-minLength` and show them if `$touched` and `$invalid` `true`. I have used UI-route to show different page in slides(using `ngAnimate`) on a single page. When we click the `button` to move on next slide it show the validation message pop-up of next page as shown in image. It shows the validation message popup on page load. I have used `novalidate` on `form` tag and `formnovalidate` on `button` but not working at all.

[image]

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="registration.email"
  name="email" ng-required="true" ng-class="{errorField: (personalInfoForm.email.$invalid
 && personalInfoForm.email.$touched) || isEmailError}" ng-blur="validateUserNameAvailability()"
  ng-pattern ="emailPattern" />
<div class="errorTooltip" ng-show="isEmailError">{{emailError}}</div>
<div ng-show="personalInfoForm.email.$invalid && personalInfoForm.email.$touched && !isEmailError">
    <div ng-show="personalInfoForm.email.$error.required" class="errorTooltip">
            {!$Label.Text_You_Must_Enter_A_Value}
    </div>
   <div ng-show="personalInfoForm.email.$error.email || personalInfoForm.email.$error.pattern" class="errorTooltip">
          {!$Label.Text_Please_Enter_Valid_Email}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found fix for this issue. Firefox load angularJS slow therefore it show all validation message on page load and later hide them.
I have added one css line in starting of page that added to ui-view.

```
<style>.first-page{ display: none; }</style>
```

I have removed this css in the end of page.

```
<script>$('.first-page').css('display','block');</script>
```

I have applied this class 'first-page' on main div of page.
This resolve my issue. Now all pages loaded in ui-view component perfectly.

Note: This also resolve the content override issue on slide animation. Firefox load angular animation slow. I have hide the page till its load completely. This resolve all firefox issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please post you complete code for the form but from your description of the issue i'm guessing the button type used on the "Next" button to go to the next slide must be

```
<input type="submit">Next</input>
```

change it to button.

```
<input type="button">Next</input>
```

You must have used a common form tag for all the slides and submit the form at the end of the last slide to save the data. But by using the button type as submit on the Next button the form is getting submitted at the end of each slide. Let me know if my analysis was correct.

Comment: I have removed the type= submit from button. Issue is that it show all validation popup on page load.